# The prompt on my Bash bug when I enter too long command line

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

I am using Bash and I installed Linux RasPi 5.15.0-1024-raspi #26-Ubuntu on my Raspberry Pi.

When I type a too long command on my bash the cursor goes at the beginning of the line and replace my username and hostname like this:

[image]

I am losing my focus and it seems to create other issues when the command line is too long.

What should I do? I presently use my raspberry pi to practice for a linux course. Should I just flash again my SD card with RasPi 5.15.0-1024-raspi #26-Ubuntu?

Comment: That is not the default prompt. If you edited, you need to follow the answer in the duplicate to escape non-printing characters like colour codes or bash will miscalculate the prompt length and show problems like this one.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution so I flashed the SD card of my Raspberry Pi, now it's fix, I had that issue for so long.